# Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero error

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-entities

im geting the next error:

> Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than
>   the size of the argument list.

and im not sure what it means, this is my code:

```
 var gruposA = db_cm.Permisos_Grupo_User.Include("Permisos_Grupo")
                            .Where(g => g.id_user == id && model.grupos.Any(x => int.Parse(x.Value) == g.id_grupo))
                            .ToList();
```

can someone tell me wath is wrong?

model.grupos is an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>`

what i need to do is select a list of `cm.Permisos_Grupo_User` if the id is on `model.grupos`

Comment: you need to break this up. Try var gruposA = db_cm.Permisos_Grupo_User.Include("Permisos_Grupo") and see if that fails. If not, add the first half of the Where, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, adding a .ToList() fixed the problem

```
db_cm.Permisos_Grupo_User.Include("Permisos_Grupo").ToList()
                            .Where(g => g.id_user == id && model.grupos.Any(x => int.Parse(x.Value) == g.id_grupo))
                            .ToList();
```